# Why do I have more reputation then I earned?

Tags: discussion

I just got off a years suspension and all my posts have down votes. I don't understand why my reputation does not reflect that? I know I get 100 rep from being a member but not the rest of it. I'm not complaining but still interested to know if down votes count when your suspended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every SE account profile has a reputation tab that shows the accumulation of rep for that account.  The tab for [your account](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/users/4139/muze?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=1) on the main site will provide the history of your rep accumulation.

There are a number of votes (both up and down) during the latter part of 2017, so it appears that rep continues to accumulate during a suspension.

Comment: Yes but I should have less rep according to my votes.

Comment: Never mind I see how.  There are some up votes but more down votes, but still earning reputation and a suspension.

Comment: Fore example: 3 up votes = +15 rep and 4 down votes = -8 rep showing a down vote on my question but +8 in rep.